# Ionic build error with Cordova Inappbrowser

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

I have added the Cordova Inappbrowser plugin to my blank Ionic project, but when I try to build or emulate the project I get a nasty build error:

```
2014-08-20 01:41:39.181 xcodebuild[95617:3d23]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /SourceCache/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-5069/Xcode3Core/LegacyProjects/Frameworks/DevToolsCore/DevToolsCore/SpecificationTypes/BuiltInSpecifications/Compilers/XCGccMakefileDependencies.m:76
Details:  Failed to load dependencies output contents from ``/Users/johndoe/Coding/temp/fb-test/platforms/ios/build/fb-test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/fb-test.build/Objects-normal/i386/CDVInAppBrowser.d''. Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “CDVInAppBrowser.d” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo=0x7f94945e9260 {NSFilePath=/Users/johndoe/Coding/temp/fb-test/platforms/ios/build/fb-test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/fb-test.build/Objects-normal/i386/CDVInAppBrowser.d, NSUnderlyingError=0x7f9494731fc0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"}. User info: {
    NSFilePath = "/Users/johndoe/Coding/temp/fb-test/platforms/ios/build/fb-test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/fb-test.build/Objects-normal/i386/CDVInAppBrowser.d";
    NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. No such file or directory\"";
}.
Function: void XCGccMakefileDependenciesParsePathsFromRuleFile(NSString *__strong, void (^__strong)(NSString *__strong))
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7f94945e92a0>{name = (null), num = 7}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileC build/fb-test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/fb-test.build/Objects-normal/i386/CDVInAppBrowser.o fb-test/Plugins/org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser/CDVInAppBrowser.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
Error: /Users/johndoe/Coding/temp/fb-test/platforms/ios/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 65
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:755:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:822:5)
```

Does my version of Xcode (beta2) maybe need updating? Or is there maybe a bug with inappbrowser?

Comment: try removing the plugins folder at the project root remove the folder ios from platform. Do ionic platform add ios and rebuild. Worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me. 
first update ios-sim: npm install ios-sim.
Then create a folder called org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser in platforms/ios/yourAppName/Plugins.
Then go to plugins/org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser/src/ios folder and copy the CDVInAppBrowser.h and CDVInAppBrowser.m files to the folder you created earlier (platforms/ios/yourAppName/Plugins/org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser).

This is all after you install inappbroswer: $ cordova plugins add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser

See https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-07-25-ionic-simple-login.html for more info. 
If  you are trying to install other plugins, follow same steps. For some reason the .h and .m files are not generated inside platforms/ios/... files.

Comment: Thanks. This solved it for me. I'm going to drop a note to the ionic folks as well.

Comment: I got "build succeeded", but when I try to run it in the iOS emulator, I got this error: 

(Domain = FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain, Code = 4), Unable to run app in Simulator}
Error: myApp/platforms/ios/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:766:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:833:5)

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue. I went to `platforms/ios` and removed `build` folder completely which helped me and the app runs fine now.

Comment: I had the same issue when I installed the cordova phone plugin, and this what solved my issue. Thank you :)